# How to parse single-string array to hash in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, parsing, hash, converters

I have a Ruby array (don't ask me why it is not hash already, i can't do anything about it):

```
[{":cost=>100", ":size=>2"}]
```

What do i need to do to make it the classical Ruby hash with keys and values?
What is my best option? Maybe there is some libraries for this kind of  operations?

Thanks.

Comment: You posted invalid code. I think you misplaced (or inserted) the `{}`.

Comment: Maybe `eval('{' + [":cost=>100", ":size=>2"].join(',') + '}')`?

Comment: Actually no. This is what i get with "puts" command when i try to validate the data visually. And i get the "Array" class when i'm printing the class name of this object with puts(MyClass.class).

Comment: @AlexSid, you mean, if you do `you_obj.to_s` you get `"[{\":cost=>100\", \":size=>2\"}]"`?

Comment: You show an array. If it's a string, show a string (I.e., enclose in single or double quotes).

Comment: @SilverPhoenix, you perfectly undestood what am i getting. There is escape symbols before double quotes if i try to convert this to string. Also there is no escape symbols if i just use "puts" with this object.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, sorry, probably i've not formulated my question specific enough. I have done things with arrays in Ruby before, but i don't know how to call the print which i'm getting. Because this is the array, but it's have {} quotes in it. I'm getting this array in legacy project that i have to maintain, so only option for me is to convert this into something useful because i can't change code that gives me that array.

Comment: I meant you should edit to show the string as  `'[{":cost=>100", ":size=>2"}]'`. Perhaps even write `'[{":cost=>100", ":size=>2"}]'
 #=> "[{\":cost=>100\", \":size=>2\"}]"`.

Comment: Why can't you do anything about it? This is something completely broken in whatever is giving you this string.

Answer (score 1):

First we need to clean the string to make it look like a valid array:

```
my_string = my_string[2..-3]
my_array = eval("[#{my_string}]")
```

Now you can join the strings, and then eval it into a hash:

```rb
elements = my_array.join(', ')
my_hash = eval("{ #{ elements } }")
```

(this can be done in fewer lines, but I separated them for clarity)

Comment: It's worth noting that whenever using `eval` that you should be **extra super careful** not to execute arbitrary strings. Be absolutely sure this data comes from a trusted source.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [JSON](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) module to do that. That would arguably be safer than by using `eval`.

To see how `JSON` could be used, let's do some reverse-engineering. You want to create a hash:

```
h = { :cost=>100, :size=>2 }
```

from the string:

```
str = '[{":cost=>100", ":size=>2"}]'
  #=> "[{\":cost=>100\", \":size=>2\"}]"
```

Let's see how that hash would be encoded as a JSON string:

```
require 'json'
jstr = JSON.generate(h)
  #=> "{\"cost\":100,\"size\":2}"
```

Once we have `jstr` (which is nothing more than a string) we can extract the desired hash:

```
JSON.parse(jstr)
  #=> {"cost"=>100, "size"=>2}
```

so the task reduces to converting `str` to `jstr`:

```
  "[{\":cost=>100\", \":size=>2\"}]" => "{\"cost\":100,\"size\":2}"
```

Perhaps the easiest way is to first pull out the keys and values, which we can do with a regex:

```
r = /
    (       # start capture group 1
      [a-z] # match a lowercase letter
      \w*   # match >= 0 word characters
    )       # close capture group 1
    =>      # match characters
    (-?\d+) # optionally match a minus sign followed by > 0 digits in
            # capture group 2
    /x      # free-spacing regex definition mode

arr = str.scan r
  #=> [["cost", "100"], ["size", "2"]]
```

We can now form `jstr`:

```
jstr = "{#{ arr.map { |k,v| "\"#{k}\":#{v}" }.join(",") }}" 
  #=> "{\"cost\":100,\"size\":2}"
```

To confirm,

```
h = JSON.parse(jstr)
  #=> {"cost"=>100, "size"=>2}
```